# Azure Function App: Http Trigger vs. Timer Trigger

Tags: azure-functions

I am trying to determine which Azure Function I should use (between Http Trigger vs. Timer Trigger).

I have SDK which has logic to pull data from a third party API (using Web Service).

Since I only need to pull data once a day, I think Timer Trigger would work.

I am trying to also move data from Azure Function to Azure Data Factory (ADF) for next portion of my project.

**My question is, what are best cases to use Http Trigger?**

I learned that Http Trigger has a webhook where it automatically triggers ADF (Azure Data Factory).

I have read and watched YouTube videos about Http Trigger, but they did not explain about "When" to use.

It mentioned about "Http Request" which I believe is something made by a client, but I, as a client, do not know when data gets updated, correct?

I am not sure how Http Trigger gets triggered.

**Does Http Trigger trigger when data from source changes?**

If that is the case, Http Trigger and ADF can run anytime throughout the day, correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. what are best cases to use Http Trigger?

In my work, I use Http Trigger when the final user or an API will trigger the action, for example when the user click on a button in the front, it will trigger the azure function that do a certain action.

2. Does Http Trigger trigger when data from source changes?

No, Http trigger will be triggered only when the the http request consumed/called .

Comment: How do we schedule Http Trigger to run? Is it only be possible by running ADF (Azure Data Factory)? My next question is: my SDK uses Web Services. If that is the case, do I have to use Http Trigger?

Comment: Case 1 : you create a Timer Trigger if you want to schedule the azure function to be executed each day.
Case 2 : you create an HTTP Trigger, and you create another process that consume it, for example you create an azure function that use HTTP trigger and you create a logic apps that has a schedule trigger that consume that API or a cran job that consume the azure function.
- the trigger depends on the scenario. if you want to pull data once a day it's better to use time trigger, even if you use time trigger, even if AZ function is time triggered, it can consume HTTP requests.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got stuck on "using web services" on documentation for my SDK, so I wanted to get confirmation whether I could use Timer Trigger. Since you mentioned that Timer Trigger is ok with web services, I would just create Timer Trigger and connect with Azure Data Factory to pull data. Would Azure Data Factory work? Thank you bunch!

Comment: if you want to move data Azure Data Factory is the way to go. ( ps: if the azure function rôle is just to trigger the Azure Data Factory you can configure a Timer trigger directly in ADF https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory )

Comment: Does Http Trigger require using Rest API?