# Http Trigger vs Time trigger, azure function app

Tags: triggers, azure-functions

I have azure function app in which I want to use trigger. But I want to know when to use HTTP trigger and when to use Timer Trigger. Which will be more budget friendly and better to use.

I have seen many articles and you tube videos. Every where they had explained what is http and timer trigger. Not the complete difference where I can find answer considering pricing, performance and use case all together.

Answer (score 0):

**Http trigger:** It is used to trigger manually when you need your Azure function to execute. For example, clicking on the button to run or execute

**Timer Trigger:**: It is used when you need to execute a function on a predetermined schedule, no matter if you are offline or online. It will trigger at the specified time.

Coming to the pricing of the function trigger, Azure Function is charged only when your function is run or executed. The cost may differ as per your usage of the trigger or processing. Costs will depend on how often the function runs and its execution time.

I have created HTTP Trigger **"skilltest"**. Http Trigger is executed as per my requirement, when I want to run the trigger.
[image]

[image]

[image]

I have created TimerTrigger **TimerTrigger** which runs every 10 min.
CORN expression for running every 10min `0 */10 * * * *`

**Function.json**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */10 * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can check this [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69904213/azure-function-app-http-trigger-vs-timer-trigger?rq=2) for reference.

You can check cost/charges of the Azure Function as your usage using [Azure Pricing Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/)(mentioned in Pricing calculator for Function)

> The first 400,000 GB/s of execution and 1,000,000 executions are free.

Answer (score 0):

> I have azure function app in which I want to use trigger. But I want to know when to use HTTP trigger and when to use Timer Trigger.

An Azure function never runs without a trigger. There are numerous triggers, a timer trigger and http trigger are just two of the [many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings?tabs=isolated-process%2Cpython-v2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#add-bindings-to-a-function).

So in the end, which trigger you need depends on what you want your function to react to.

Some basic examples scenarios for which a **timer trigger** will be useful are

- Generating a daily report and send it per email
- Connect to a database and clean up records on a regular interval

When you have need to schedule some work, the timer trigger is your friend.
Some basic examples scenarios for which an **http trigger** will be useful are

- You want to process a [web hook](https://hookdeck.com/webhooks/guides/what-are-webhooks-how-they-work)
- You have a web app and want to delegate some work to an out-of-process application (an azure function in this case). Your web app then performs an http request to the azure function.

But there are many more triggers, like queue triggers than can help to build more resilient applications for example. If you post your use case we might be able to better guide you.

> Which will be more budget friendly and better to use.

The trigger does not define the costs. If you are running the functions on a consumption plan you pay for the resources (memory and CPU used) during the execution.